# zsh: stop backward-kill-word on directory delimiter

Tags: zsh

In [zsh](http://www.zsh.org/), how can I set up the line editor such that `backward-kill-word` stops on a directory separator?  Currently in my bash setup, if I type

```
cd ~/devel/sandbox
```

and then hit `C-w` point will be right after `devel/`.  In my zsh setup, point would be after `cd` .  I'd like to set up zsh so it behaves similarly to bash.

Comment: This might be a readline issue, I should add...

Answer (score -4, accepted):

A quick google reveals:

[Backward Kill](http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2001/msg00870.html)

Or, perhaps a better fix:

[Bash Style Backward Kill](http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2001/msg00868.html)

Comment: For future readers: both of the other answers are strictly better and easier.

Comment: link-only answers are discouraged as the link may die. Please include the relevant part in your answer

Comment: Not a good answer and snarky as well "All you have to do is google the solution". I'll give this a down vote.

Comment: @Emil, indeed, that's a better solution than the ones presented here. For posterity, I'll copy the gist of it here
1) Define a new function `tcsh-backward-delete-word () {
    local WORDCHARS="${WORDCHARS:s#/#}";
    zle backward-delete-word;
}` 2) Register it with ZSH `zle -N tcsh-backward-delete-word` 3) Add a keybinding `bindkey '^W' tcsh-backward-delete-word`.

Answer (score 117):

For recent versions of zsh, you can simply add:

```
autoload -U select-word-style
select-word-style bash
```

to your zshrc as described in [the zsh manual](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#Widgets) (also `man zshcontrib`).

Comment: This is probably fairly specific, but if this doesn't work, it may be because of the zsh-syntax-highlighting plugin: https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting/issues/67. Make sure to source that plugin at the end of your zshrc.

Comment: This works, but only partially, i.e. jump a word forward and back still considers `/` to be a part of a word.

Comment: Ah, I fixed it, turns out for whatever reason the two lines should be at the very beginning of the file.

Comment: Note that for some reasons this work for the function `backward-kill-word` but not for `backward-delete-word` (the later should not copy the result in the yank ring)

Answer (score 88):

Another option is to set `WORDCHARS` (non-alphanumeric chars treated as part of a word) to something that doesn't include `/`.

You can also tweak this if you'd prefer `^w` to break on dot, underscore, etc.  In `~/.zshrc` I have:

```
WORDCHARS='*?_-.[]~=&;!#$%^(){}<>'
```

Comment: I can't find this explicitly mentioned in the manual but setting `WORDCHARS` to empty string (i.e: add the line `WORDCHARS=` to `.zshrc`) has the same effect.

Comment: The empty string doesn't include `/` 

Comment: I don’t want to hardcode the `$WORDCHARS`, so I used `WORDCHARS=${WORDCHARS/\/}` to remove slash from it.

Comment: Just `WORDCHARS=` gives the best effect imo

Comment: Building on Franklin's answer, `${WORDCHARS//[\/]}` allows removing several characters by including them in the square brackets.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what worked for me. `unspecified` word-style was required otherwise zsh didn't seem to respect the `WORDCHARS`.`enter code here`

```bash
WORDCHARS=' *?_-.[]~=&;!#$%^(){}<>/'
autoload -Uz select-word-style
select-word-style normal
zstyle ':zle:*' word-style unspecified
```

[Here's more info on why this works.](http://mikebian.co/fixing-word-navigation-in-zsh/)

Comment: This is the only solution on this page that worked for me thanks! - Macos ZSH