# How to get Cmd-left/right working with iTerm2 and Vim (without requiring .vimrc changes)?

Tags: macos, shell, vim, keyboard-shortcuts, iterm

I want to be able to use Option-left and Option-right to skip words (and Cmd-left/right to go to beginning and end of lines) within Vim as it does at my shell prompt.  My Iterm2 preferences have mappings to do this (e.g. `Option-left` to `Esc-H` and a one for `option-right` to `Esc-F` to skip over words), and this works in the shell locally or when ssh'd to a remote server.

When I use Vim locally or remotely, `option-left` works, but `option-right` does not. I suspect this is because Vim naturally listens for `Esc-H`, but not `Esc-F`.  I am able to get around this by modifying .vimrc file to `Esc-b` to `b` and `Esc-f` to `f`, but I don't want to do this to every server I'm connecting to.

Similarly, I have the same desired setup for Cmd-left/right for going to beginning and end of a line.  I can get this working in the shell via Iterm2 mappings (e.g. `Cmd-left` to `Esc-[h`), but Vim doesn't respond at all to this unless I map keys again (e.g. `Esc-[h` to `^`).

**Update:** I just figured out how to get option-left/right working. I changed mapping in iTerm2 for these to be `escape-[1;5D` and `escape-[1;5C` respectively.  I still want to solve the Cmd-left/right problem though (I changed my question's title to reflect this). Any ideas?

Comment: Neither your shell nor Vim are going to react to the `Cmd` key. Also, as a long time mac user, I find `^$bBeEwW` to be far more efficient: if you are going to use Vim seriously, why not use it as it was designed?

Comment: @romainl are you sure? It worked for me on linux, Windows and Solaris and across terminal emulators like screen and/or Putty

Comment: Yes. Pressing the `Cmd` key is not registered by the shell (no ANSI code for modifier `Cmd`) so AFAIK there is no way to send `Cmd` to Vim which doesn't even understand `Cmd` anyway: it's MacVim-only, no other versions of Vim, CLI or GUI, on any OS, can use `<D->` mappings. So, the only way to use the `Cmd` key in CLI Vim mappings is to swap it with some other key: `Alt`, `Ctrl`, `Shift`, whatever, there are lots of apps/hacks for that. Obviously, doing that may open the door to an avalanche of problems and, *actually* displace the problem since we still have the same number of modifier keys.

Comment: That's when you see the brilliance of modal editing and single key commands.

Comment: I already have iTerm2 mapping Cmd+left/right mapping to other keys, so I don't need Vim to listen for that, but instead, if there is some other Escape/hex code that Vim supports by default as an alterative to "$" and "^", then perhaps I can update my mappings to use that.  For example, Home and End keys work on a standard Linux install.  Any idea what key-sequence those send?

Comment: What do you mean? You were asking specifically about sending `Cmd`+something to Vim via iTerm2. Now you say that you already have `Cmd`+`left/right` mapped to other keys (which ones? how?) in iTerm2 and now want to do what with `Home`/`End` and `^`/`$`? Could you explain what it is you want to achieve? What's wrong with Vim's default mappings?

Comment: @romainl - Vim's mappings are fine, but I prefer for Vim to also support the same behavior of most other Mac applications in that option-left/right skips words, and cmd-left/right goes to beginning/end of lines. Call me a Vim rookie, but I'm set in my ways.  My goal is to not modify Vim to support this (since I'd need to add .vimrc entries on all servers I use), but instead to use iTerm2's key-mapping to do this.  I believe one way is to have iTerm2 mimic the Home/End keys, which Vim recognizes by default, at least on the Ubuntu installs I've used.  Sorry for any confusion

Comment: So you want iTerm2 to send `$` to Vim when you type `Cmd`+`right` and `^` when you type `Cmd`+`left`. Am I right? I **really** think you shouldn't do that but the solution is extremely easy: in iTerm's prefs, under "Keys", click the `+`, press `Cmd`+`right`, choose "Send text" from the dropdown menu and type `$`. Do the same for your other shortcut and you are set.

Comment: Problem with mapping `cmd-left/right` to `^/$` is the shell will use the mapping as well. I think using the `Home/End` keys is the way to go, so what I've done is map `cmd-left` to `Escape-[H`, and that works fine in shell, but not in Vim. When I connect a keyboard with a `Home` key, this works in Vim, but if I use the command `read` in Unix/Linux to intercept key combinations of `Cmd-Left` and `Home`, they both output `^[[H`.  Any ideas on why Vim sees these two commands differently when `read` sees them as same?

Comment: I finally figured it out. I'll explain in an answer below. Thanks all for the patience and help!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To mimic OS X's behavior of sending `Cmd-left/right` to the beginning/end of a line, I add the following mappings in iTerm2:

- `Cmd-left` to escape-sequence `[1~`
- `Cmd-right` to escape-sequence `[4~`

To mimic OS X's behavior of sending `Option-left/right` to the previous/next word, I add the following mappings in iTerm2:

- `Option-left` to escape-sequence `[1;5D`
- `Option-right` to escape-sequence `[1;5C`

Special thanks to [this blog post](http://keith.chaos-realm.net/archives/198-OSX-Terminal-Home-End-Keys.html) for tracking down what I was missing with the `cmd-left/right` mappings

Comment: Note: this doesn't work in my local python shell on OS X, but when ssh'd to linux machine, these work in python shell. No idea why.  If I use the mappings ilias mentioned below, they don't work in Vim, but everywhere else, including python they work

Comment: The python shell in OS X doesn't use readline unless you install https://pypi.python.org/pypi/readline

Comment: This works nice in `vim` but it doesn't work in `bash` (e.g. when writing a long command) :(

Comment: Hi @DolanAntenucci , what the equivalent mappings would be in .vimrc (my workflow is Terminal.app, tmux, and vim)? Something like map <M-Left> [1;5D and <M-Right> [1;5C ?

Comment: @JohnSkilbeck - I'm not sure anymore what mappings would work in .vimrc; lately I'm just using the standard vim shortcuts along with the iterm changes I mentioned above. Not ideal for me, but just been too lazy to get vim working with these shortcuts

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much, for me it work both in VIM & bash 3 (OS X).

Comment: Neither this solution, nor Karim's worked for my Cmd-left/right bindings. I had to set `bindkey '^[[1~' beginning-of-line` and `bindkey '^[[4~' end-of-line` in my `~/.zshrc`, then I was able to set the escape codes per this answer. Everything works as expected now in both iTerm2 and Vim.

Answer (score 25):

I'm using iTerm2 3.4.2 and there's actually a preset that you can select for your profile that enables this.
[image: Profile Key Mappings]
[image: Natural Text Editing Preset]

Comment: This doesn't seem to work as expected for me. The behavior of the mappings doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Should mention I am using iTerm 3.4.22 on MacOS 14.1 (Sonoma)

Comment: Thank you for this! I can confirm this works perfectly with CMD, Option + left/right as you'd expect. 

I'm on iTerm 2 Build 3.4.22 on Sonoma 14.2 Beta 3

Answer (score 11):

FWIW, dolan's answer didn't work for me on iTerm 2 1.0.0.20120203 on Mac OS X 10.7.3. His solution only inserted `~` and `5D`/`5C` into my terminal when I pressed the shortcut keys.

Instead, I used the following solutions:

- `Cmd-left/right`:
  [iTerm 2: How to set keyboard shortcuts to jump to beginning/end of line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205157/iterm2-how-to-get-jump-to-beginning-end-of-line-in-bash-shell)
- `Option-left/right` as well as `option-delete`:
  http://hackaddict.blogspot.co.at/2007/07/skip-to-next-or-previous-word-in-iterm.html

YMMV, not sure why one set of solutions would work and not the other

Comment: I'm running the same versions of iTerm 2 and OS X. I am using "xterm-256color" as my Terminal Type with "Unicode (UTF-8)" as my character encoding. Maybe see if you have a different setting there?

Comment: I have the same settings. I tried entering your escape codes into both Keys and Profiles > Keys, same effect. Don't know what could be different

Comment: I found that your settings and my settings both work on the command line, but I get different behavior with each in Vim and the Python shell. My settings don't work in Python shell (does ~/5D/5C as you mention), and in Vim (default `vim`, not MacVim), your settings trigger some other functionality or don't work depending which command I'm using (e.g cmd-right scrolls window one line). If you get a chance, check out if Vim has the above commands working. Can you also clarify if you get ~/5D/5C at command line

Comment: As @evan-krall [commented above](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9611698/484127), when readline is used, readline overtakes parsing input (including what to do with escape sequences), so [configuring special keys in it's config file is required](https://code.google.com/p/iterm2/wiki/Keybindings#About_readline).

Answer (score 1):

I don't have MacOS, so I cannot exactly know your situation, but I recognize the problem from other OSes.

Basically, it would mean that the terminal sends keycodes that aren't understood by vim. I fixed it in the past by doing

```
 TERM=something
 export TERM
```

before invoking vim

E.g. in order to get all keys **and** syntax highlighting working on AIX 5.3 across Putty/screen, I needed to use

```
 TERM=iris-ansi vim
```

There is a list of builtin terminal types if you pass a bad TERM

Comment: I assume this would require adding this variable on remote servers I connect to.  Also, iTerm2 lets me change which terminal type it emulates (currently set to "xterm", but there are others like "xterm256-color"), so maybe I need to switch terminal types? Check out my comment above about why Home/End keys work, and if there is a way to emulate that. Thanks!

Comment: @dolan AFAIR Putty and ssh have options to 'send' environment variables, which normally makes a lot more sense. I'd suggest fiddling with the TERM types to see wwhat happens