# Linux, Unix or OS X tool for displaying what keyboard typing outputs?

Tags: linux, unix, keyboard, mapping

I'm looking for a tool that will tell me what my keyboard is sending to the operating system when i push different keys.

This is to help me answer this question [How to get Cmd-left/right working with iTerm2 and Vim (without requiring .vimrc changes)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9595633/how-to-get-cmd-left-right-working-with-iterm2-and-vim-without-requiring-vimrc) which has me trying to figure out why Vim treats my iTerm2 mapping of `Cmd-left` to `Escape-[H` differently from `Home`.

I tried unix's `read`, and it says that `Home` and `Cmd-left` both produce "^[[H".  I'm hoping that `read` is misleading me, and that some other tool will show how `Home` and `Cmd-left` are different (note: when I say, `Cmd-left` in this paragraph, it is when iTerm2's mapping is turned on).

Thanks!

Comment: Would be helpful if downvoters would explain why I'm being downvoted. The question is clearly different from my other question.

Comment: "keyboard" has very different meaning under X11 and in raw console (without any graphical desktop). You could be interested in using `xev` on Linux (or other X11 environment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing all this in a terminal, right?

I'm afraid you're not going to do much better than `read` (my preferred approach is to do `cat > file`, type, press `^D`, and then look at the file in a hex editor).

With regard to the underlying question, it's worth hunting for options in your terminal emulator. Right now it's emulating a terminal which doesn't distinguish between HOME and CMD+LEFT. It may be possible to tell it to emulate a different terminal, which does.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this hex editor approach.  This is in iTerm2 by the way (a Terminal-like app)