# How to make iTerm2 appear on the current screen?

Tags: macos, iterm2, osx-yosemite

Under `Preferences -> 'Keys'` It is possible to tick `Show/hide iTerm2 with a system-wide hotkey`.

However iTerm always appears on the main display (monitor) instead of where the cursor currently resides.

e.g. if I have three monitors, and am working on the third screen, the hotkey makes iTerm appear on first monitor, instead of where I am currently working.

Any advice how to solve this please?

UPDATE:

The bug strikes back again in v.3.1.6.  If any workarounds are known, please share.

Comment: Funny, how other iTerm2 questions aren't voted to be closed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205157/iterm2-how-to-get-jump-to-beginning-end-of-line-in-bash-shell

Comment: Create a new `Space`, right click on the iTerm2 icon in the dock, then assign it to whatever display...

Comment: Thanks, not sure if I understood you. It isn't about `space`. I have three monitors connected to the laptop. iTerm2 should appear on the desktop where I press the hotkey. Currently it always appears on the same desktop, no matter where I am working.

Comment: I'm not talking about `space`, but rather creating one so your app does what you want it to. I'm surprised that you run three displays and don't know about [Spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaces_%28software%29)? The functionality is built into [Mission Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mission_Control_%28OS_X%29), and gives you ability to decide where and how apps appear on your displays (virtual or real).

Comment: I don't understand either what @l'L'l is is suggesting. Houman did you managed to get the desired behaviour because I have the same problem. Would be great if you could explain how to do it if you understand it.

Comment: No @Stamy, I eventually gave up on iTerm2 and am using TotalTerminal instead.

Comment: I like this functionality so much, with el capitan they added extra security so in order to use TotalTerminal I have to disable it. To make things even more TotalTerminal stopped development and recommends to use iTerm2. So if you manage to find a solution later, please do share.

Comment: Sure will do. What a shame. Nothing beats `Guake`. A shame Mac doesn't have it.

Comment: @Houman I'm using iterm2.9. It seems this version has solved the problem already.

Comment: @sel-fish can you direct me how exactly? I notice this option to "screen: screen with cursor" in profiles -> window but it doesn't seem to affect. Is there another setting option that I'm missing? Thanks!

Comment: @BoazRymland, I'm not sure because I didn't mean to change any setting related to that. I think I should describe my actions, first, I set 'Show/hide iTerm2 with a system-wide hotkey'; then, press that hot-key, the iTerm2 window hides; then, move my cursor to another screen; then press the hot-key, the iTerms windows appears on the screen where cursor stays. Is that action what you want ?

Comment: @sel-fish that's exactly what I am looking for however with me the terminal stays on the same screen after showing / hiding. Could you tell me what settings you are using to make this work?

Comment: @Fraak I haven't used this feature for days. After received your comment, I test again and find it doesn't work anymore.. I will find the solution and answer the question later :)

Comment: After (finally) getting around to upgrading to El Capitan, and switching to iTerm 2 as a consequence, I too am noticing this odd behaviour.

Comment: tried to add some log to solve but failed for now :(  https://github.com/sel-fish/iTerm2

Comment: What do you have "Space" set to in the "Window" tab in iTerm2 settings?

Comment: [Grant's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43382153/6314615) works, but you have to restart iTerm.

Comment: it seems the issue is back on 3.3.7 when using on mac os catalina

Comment: @ierdna the bug is back for a long time. Sadly no fix in sight.

Comment: There's a bug report in iterm's gitlab account: https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/issues/8536

Answer (score 58):

I'm on Sierra using iTerm 3.1 and I have the option under window to put the screen where the cursor is (bottom right drop down options). I'm using it with a hotkey.

[image: iTerm preferences]

Comment: @Houman Strange that it works for me then... Guess I'm special

Comment: use the beta version, it will work. https://iterm2.com/downloads/beta/iTerm2-3_1_beta_4.zip

Comment: It's working when opening a **new** window. When a window was previously opened, it'll not **move** to the active screen

Comment: For me this is working for creating the window but when using it the second time it opens on my primary screen (the MBP).

Comment: It worked for me for my "Visor" window on Mojave `10.14.3` and iTerm `3.2.8`.

Comment: For those using the *'Hotkey'* to open the iTerm just like Guake or Yakuake, make sure you enable this config for the profile called *'Hotkey Window'*, that made the trick for me.

Comment: its 2020 and its not working for me... neither for the hotkey or when i quit iterm and start a new window. Does this require system restart or something?

Answer (score 9):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43382153/1712683) by [Grant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1696102/grant) works.
The only thing you need to do is to install the beta version since there was a bug in the stable version.

This bug was fixed in 3.1.beta.1 https://iterm2.com/downloads.html
[image]

Here's the link to the latest beta version https://iterm2.com/downloads/beta/iTerm2-3_1_beta_4.zip

Comment: Indeed, I just downloaded Beta 4 and it finally works. It only took them two years. :D  The perfection is now reached.

Comment: FWIW, I had to restart my computer (not just `iTerm2`) before this worked for me .

Comment: The issue is back again in 3.1.6.

Comment: Does not move it to the current screen in 3.2.6 either, always stays in its current monitor

Comment: Yup, stopped working in version 3.3.12 also such a shame it's one of the best features of iterm2.

Answer (score 6):

This may be a couple more keystrokes than you were hoping for, but if you install window management software like Size Up, you can get this working with just a few keystrokes.

Maintain your `⌥Space` hotkey preference on Iterm2. Go to Size Up -> Preferences and change 'Send Window Prev Monitor' to an easy keystroke. I used `⌥1`.

Now, you can do `⌥Space` to get the terminal open and `⌥1` one or two times to get it to your monitor of choice.  It takes a couple of key combos, but not too many!

Comment: The trouble with this method is that I don't feel it actually matches what the app itself should do -- to my mind a picture of a drop-down menu in preferences saying _"Screen with cursor"_ should make the hotkey window do _exactly that_: appear on the screen with the visor.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with macos monterey and iterm 3.4.15. I'm using the hotkey to show the terminal with slide-out window. After some search on the internet I found that disabling the option on system preferences to reopen closed documents solved the issue and the hotkey is now opening terminal on the screen with cursor as it should.

mac -> System preferences -> General -> (deselect this) Close windows when quitting an app

Comment: Your using a character that is not rendering on most machines "". You might want to consider finding a UTF-8 equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the above worked for me, but [this helped](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/378274), even though the question was quite different in that thread.