# Alt key when navigating in console

Tags: macos, terminal, console, iterm2

In Ubuntu when using `Alt` modification key I can move between words using left/right arrows. But in OS X (iTerm2 actually) when pressing this key combination I get **[D** symbols. Do I need any additional libraries to make it work or how can I accomplish this for comfortable navigation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like [this post](http://www.hackaddict.net/2007/07/skip-to-next-or-previous-word-in-iterm.html) cover how to deal with this issue. Will try it.
Also, similar Stack overflow [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205157/iterm2-how-to-get-jump-to-beginning-end-of-line-in-bash-shell)