# iTerm2: How to add a keyboard shortcut for a new action in iTerm2? n action that is not an option in the dropdown?

Tags: macos, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, iterm2, iterm

I would like to add a keyboard shortcut in iTerm2 for an action that is not displayed in the "Action" dropdown, in Preferences > Keys > + in iTerm2.

[image]

The action I want is "delete a word before cursor" and "delete a word after cursor".

Notes:

- *I know there is a shortcut* (Ctrl+U/K) for those actions, but I want to replace them for another shortcut.
- There is an option in the "Action" dropdown which consists in sending an hexadecimal code corresponding to an action. But how do I know which hexa code means that specific action? Is there any hexa-action mapping for me to able to do that?

Comment: What about this answer?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205157/iterm-2-how-to-set-keyboard-shortcuts-to-jump-to-beginning-end-of-line/29403520#29403520

Answer (score 0):

**Delete one word to left of cursor**

> <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> Delete Send Hex Codes:
>
> `0x1b 0x08` Breaks in Elixir's IEX, seems to work fine everywhere else
>
> or
>
> `0x17` Works everywhere, but doesn't stop at normal word breaks in IRB
>   and will instead delete until it sees a literal space.

**Delete one word to right of cursor**

> <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>←Delete</kbd> or <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>Delete→</kbd> Send Hex Codes: `0x1b 0x64`