# Reproducing Terminal.app's scrollback to previous prompt in iTerm2

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings, iterm2, terminal-emulator, terminal.app

By default Terminal.app has a keybinding for <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> that scrolls the screen back to (and briefly highlights) the previous command prompt. (This seems to be independent of shell although I've only tried a couple. I'm using bash.)

I'm trying to get similar behavior in iTerm2, but I haven't found a mapping that does that. None of the search terms I've tried in iTerm2's list of key mappings suggest anything like this function. The iTerm2 mapping preset called `Terminal.app Compatibility` causes <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> to scroll through previous commands, the same way <kbd>↑</kbd> does, rather than the window scrolling back to the lines on which previous commands were input.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28024652/14974911) to a similar question, I looked through the output of `bind -p` and see entries `"\e[A": previous-history` and `"\e[B": next-history`, but these seem to be describing the scrolling through previously-entered commands rather than scrolling through the entire terminal window output to the prompt at which the command was input. These are the only `bind -p` entries that refer to up or down arrows (if my assumption is correct that `[A` refers to the up arrow, which I determined with `xxd -psd` as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47710646/14974911).

Is this behavior in Terminal.app the result of a key binding? Or, how would I determine whether it is or not? And is there a way to get iTerm2 to duplicate this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [shell integration](https://iterm2.com/documentation-shell-integration.html) installed, iTerm2 creates a "mark" at each prompt, and the  default shortcut for moving to the previous mark is <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried
**`fn + CMD + UpArrow`** ?

Only an ersatz for Terminal.app *"going up one prompt at a time”* behavior, but maybe helpful as it makes **iTerm2** do a **Full Page Up** consistently across my custom profiles and various key map preferences.